# How do I just rebuild the ab binary in apache2-utils on Linux without rebuilding all of apache?

Tags: dpkg

(I'm using Debian).

I downloaded source for apache2-utils via apt-get source.
I just need to apply a patch that applies to ab.c, and I've applied it.
I could rebuild everything using dpkg which will rebuild everything in apache2-*, but how do I just build the ab part of this package (to save time)?

I see the directory that contains the ab source contains ab.mak and a Makefile.in.  Anyway to shortcut the build time?